# Word file created by IIS using OpenXML continues to be locked by IIS after disposal

Tags: c#, iis, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have some word templates with .docm extensions which contain tokenised identifiers which will be substituted with actual values from a database.

I am loading the template, cloning it and changing the document type from template to document before saving it off as a new document to disk:

```
string templateFilePath = @"C:\TempDoc\Template.docm";

using (WordprocessingDocument template = WordprocessingDocument.CreateFromTemplate(templateFilePath))
{
    using (WordprocessingDocument document = (WordprocessingDocument)template.Clone())
    {
        document.ChangeDocumentType(WordprocessingDocumentType.Document);

        document.SaveAs(@"C:\TempDoc\Template.docx");
    }   
}
```

All of this works but the newly created file remains locked by W3WP process and then can't be read and streamed back out of the service.

Any idea how to prevent IIS from holding on to this file?

The same code can be run in LinqPad and the new document is immediately unlocked as soon as the using block goes out of scope as expected.

Comment: What leads you to believe that the file is locked by W3WP? I.e. what error message or similar are you seeing? It may be relevant to the question...

Comment: Thanks for you reply. When I try to open the file from disk, Word tells that it can't be opened because its already in use. When I use Unlocker to find out which process has the file locked, it shows W3WP.

Answer (score 4):

Found a workaround:

```
        File.Copy(templateFilePath, documentFilePath, true);
        using (WordprocessingDocument document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(documentFilePath, true))
        {
            document.ChangeDocumentType(WordprocessingDocumentType.Document);
```

Instead of using Clone and SaveAs, which leaves the lock, if I file copy the template, modify that and Save as opposed to SaveAs, no lock is maintained.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`SaveAs()` is actually the same as `Clone()` (see [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.packaging.openxmlpackage.saveas?view=openxml-2.8.1#DocumentFormat_OpenXml_Packaging_OpenXmlPackage_SaveAs_System_String_)). So it doesn't just create a file, but also opens the package, so to remove the lock you should `Close()` it.

```
document.SaveAs(@"C:\TempDoc\Template.docx").Close();
```